# Postgresql multi insert from array of composite type and one additional column

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, postgresql-9.2

What I have:

```
CREATE TYPE Item AS (
    a bigint,
    b bigint
);

CREATE TABLE items (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    a bigint NOT NULL,
    b bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION items_insert(
        _id bigint,
        _items Item[]
) RETURNS void AS
...
```

How can I insert multi <s>columns</s> rows to table items with same _id from _items by ONE multi insert query?

I am using Postgresql-9.2

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean "insert multiple *rows*" rather than columns.

Assuming that is correct, I think you are looking for a function like this:

```
create or replace function items_insert(_id bigint, _items item[]) 
  returns void 
as
$$
  insert into items (id, a, b)
  select _id, it.*
  from unnest(_items) as it(a,b);
$$
language sql;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=1eeb6f8e2fdea5f3099fe996b077ba46)

Comment: Thanks for advance. I found shorter way:
`INSERT INTO items(id, a, b) SELECT _id, (unnest(_items)).*;`

Comment: @КонстантинПрименко: using `unnest()` in the SELECT list is not recommended. It's better to use it in the FROM clause

Comment: Why using `unnest()` in the `SELECT` list is not recommended?